# How to find user's and groups accociated to a particular Content in ektron?

Tags: ektron

Am am working on ektron 9.0.

Suppose i have a content in workarea, and had permissions to some users and groups.
How can i find the user's and groups associated with that particular content by ektron api?

Any help on this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all the users and groups that have sufficient privileges to edit the content?

Comment: No. just need the list of users and groups linked to that content, assume that they have at-least one permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var permissionManager = new PermissionManager(ApiAccessMode.Admin);
var criteria = new PermissionCriteria();

criteria.AddFilter(PermissionProperty.ContentId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, contentId);

List<UserPermissionData> permissionDataList = permissionManager.GetList(criteria);
```

The list of UserPermissionData objects contains a UserId property so you can see what users have permission to that content item.  More info can be found in [Ektron's documentation](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/edr/web/edr.htm#FrameworkAPI/Settings/PermissionManager.htm).